# Cogs aren't loading pycord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I made a bot with basic commands and a cog for every moderation command. When I start the bot, I only have access to the commands on main.py and not the ones in the cogs.

I used this load function:

```py
@bot.event
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
            print(f"Loaded Cog: {filename[:-3]}")
        else:
            print("Unable to load pycache folder.")
```

none of the prints shows up in the console and i have no error

Here is the setup function in the cog:

```py
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(bot)
```

Comment: I'm not known to the pycord fork, but I think that you mistook how the `@bot.event` decorator works. It's using your function name a the name of the event. you should rename your function to `on_ready` and make sure that this code is only being called once, e.g. by a variable called `ready` that you set to `True` when the first `on_ready` event is fired and check if it is `False` in an if-statement in the first line of the function

Answer (score 1):

**Your code:**

```
@bot.event
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
            print(f"Loaded Cog: {filename[:-3]}")
        else:
            print("Unable to load pycache folder.")
```

**First Issue:** You correctly identified that the event should be named `on_ready`, which is triggered when the bot is connected and ready. The `load()` event doesn't exist in `py-cord`.  See more about [events](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/events.html) in py-cord.

**Second Issue:** The `await` keyword is used to call asynchronous functions or methods. Since `load_extension` is not an asynchronous function, using `await` with it will result in a `TypeError`.

***Solution to it?***
By removing `await` keyword, you resolve this issue and ensure that the extensions are loaded correctly.

**Explaination:**
The `await` keyword is used to pause the execution of a [coroutine](https://betterprogramming.pub/coroutines-in-python-building-blocks-of-asynchronous-programming-40c39d9ed420) until the awaited function or operation is completed. It's typically used with [asynchronous](https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/an-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-af0189a88bbb#:%7E:text=Asynchronous%20programming%20is%20a%20type,failure%20of%20the%20worker%20thread.) operations that might take some time to finish, like making API requests or database queries. In your case, using await with a non-asynchronous function like `bot.load_extension` is unnecessary and leads to a `TypeError`.

By removing `await` in this context, you ensure that the `bot.load_extension` operation is executed synchronously and doesn't require awaiting a result, which is why the correction works.

**Correct Working Code:**

```
@bot.event #A bot event in pycord.
async def on_ready(): #when bot is connected and ready.
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'): #checking files inside the ./cogs directory.
        if filename.endswith('.py'): #checking for .py files inside ./cogs directory.
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}') #loading every .py files.
            print(f"Loaded Cog: {filename[:-3]}")
        else:
            print("No python(.py) files found!") #if can't find any .py files.
```

**Why did I changed that `else` block `print` statement?**
While your `print` statement wasn't wrong, and won't throw any errors but the purpose of that `else` statement in your code is intended to provide a message when there are no `.py` files found in the `./cogs` directory.
The `else` part comes into play when the `if` statement fails to find any `.py` files to work with. Its purpose is to handle this situation by trying executing the specified `else` code. The condition for entering the `else` when it didn't find any `.py files`, which is why it's important for understanding what's happening in the code. The reference to ***"pycache"*** not loading is not actually an issue here as it doesn't even end with `.py` as per your `if` condition, The primary reason for the else is to handle the absence of `.py` files in the specified directory.

***Hope it helps and I was able to explain you something!***:D #KeepLearning ;) #Python

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect decorator.

Use:

```
@bot.command()
```

Also, please ensure you have enabled the 'Message Content' intent on your bot application. Read more on gateway intents [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/intents.html).

You can also learn more on creating Pycord commands [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html).